# how to replace an webpage image from chrome.storage.local

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I would like to make an extension(for practice) which will erase all images of an webpage and replace those with a given/selected one. My html code is, 
***Note: I used 'ul' tag images to show in popup.html and 'div' tag images to show in webpages.

```
<ul class="image_holder">
                <li class="image_block"><img src="images/prank/prank1i.jpg" id="image1i" class="visualization image_data"></li>
                <li class="image_block"><img src="images/prank/prank2i.jpg" id="image2i" class="visualization image_data"></li>
</ul>
<div id="hidden_images">
        <img src="images/prank/prank1.png" id="image1" class="replacement_image">
        <img src="images/prank/prank2.png" id="image2" class="replacement_image">
</div>
```

My popup.js code for image replacing work is,

```
function gettingImage(replacingImage){
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = replacingImage.width;
    canvas.height = replacingImage.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.drawImage(replacingImage, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var imageData = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "")
    //var imageData = context.getImageData(0 , 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
    chrome.storage.local.set({'image': imageData});
    alert(imageData); //This show the value of imagedata.Which is a strange string. probably right.
}


document.getElementById("image1i").addEventListener("click", function(){ //same code for other image
    var imagename = "image1";
    let im = document.getElementById(imagename);
    gettingImage(im);
});
```

My content script looks like this,

```
function bodyHandler(e){

    chrome.storage.local.get('image', function(imagedata){
        if(typeof imagedata.image !== 'undefined'){
            chrome.storage.local.get('image', function(imagedata){
                replacingImage = imagedata.image;
            });
        }
    });

    var image = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for(var i=0; i<image.length; i++){
        image[i].src = replacingImage;
    }

}

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', bodyHandler, false);
```

My code does not show any error, but it does not show the image either. It turn of the webpage images but doesn't show selected image. 
*** I did try various stackoverflow answers. ***

Comment: You need to use the data inside the callback because it's asynchronous. Move your var+for right after replacingImage = imagedata.image;

Comment: It still the same. It erase images of the page but doesn't show the selected image.

Comment: Make sure you've reloaded both the extension and the web page after editing the content script. Also use devtools to debug your code.

Comment: I don't know why but after commenting the line `var imageData = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "")` it is showing the image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using `var imageData = dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpeg);base64,/, "")` line of code. It converts the image into a 64base url which is unnecessary in this case.